# List Azure certification from Microsoft Learn profile using Graph API from .net 6 Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, microsoft-graph-api, .net-6.0

I'm trying to fetch Azure certification list from my Microsoft Learn profile (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/users/kuldeepsingh/credentials/certifications) using Graph API.

Azure Functions code to generate token:

```
        string[] scopes = new string[] { $"{clientId}/.default" };

        IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create(clientId)
            .WithTenantId(tenantId)
            .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
            .Build();

        AuthenticationResult authResult = await confidentialClientApplication.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();

        string authToken = authResult.AccessToken;
        Console.WriteLine("Access token: {0}", authToken);
```

#### Steps

1. Registered an application in Azure AD with below permissions:

   - MicrosoftGraph - User.Read
   - MicrosoftGraph - Directory.Read.All
2. Generated Client Secret for registered application
3. Azure function in .net 6

   - Used above AAD app registration to generate a bearer_token
   - Call Microsoft Graph api by passing bearer_token in request header.
   - API endpoint: https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/kuldeepsingh/profile/certifications

I'm getting 401 Unauthorized error. Appreciate any help in this context.

Ref: Microsoft documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profile-list-certifications?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http

### Tried option 1

1. App registration of type `Accounts in this organizational directory only` with below permissions:

   - MicrosoftGraph - User.Read
   - MicrosoftGraph - User.Read.All
2. Generate token using below scope:

   ```
   string[] scopes = new string[] { $"https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
   ```
3. Error:

   "/me request is only valid with delegated authentication flow."

### UPDATE:

As of now there is no sync between certifications from MS learn profile and `/me/profile/certifications`. So technically we can't fetch MS Learn certification using Graph APIs.

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/resolve-auth-errors

Comment: Thank you @jdweng for sharing the link. I'm using Personal account to generate token. Not sure learn graph apis are supported for personal accounts or not. Message from MS document:

Additionally this error may occur, if you try to use a delegated access token granted to a personal Microsoft account, to access an API that only supports work or school accounts (organizational accounts)

Comment: The error may be due to having more than one Office 365 account and using wrong account; or the Office 365 account you are using isn't configured to access the data.  Use the link to troubleshoot the 401 error.

Comment: From the debug instructions it is not clear that can we use personal account or not for MS learn graph apis. Any chance, do you happen to know this?

Comment: The server has to be configured to accept your credentials.  It is a permission issue.  The error message just says you do not have permission.  It assumes you may have more than one account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Note** that: For work or school accounts, all delegated permissions are valid; however, not all of them are valid for Microsoft accounts used for personal use. Check [**this**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference).

I created an **Azure AD Application** and granted `User.Read` API permission:

[image]

I generated access token with **`User.Read`** scope:

```cs
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;

string authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID";
string clientId = "ClientID"; 
string clientSecret = "ClientSecret";

string[] scopes = new string[] { "User.Read" };

IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
    .Create(clientId)
    .WithAuthority(authority)
    .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
    .Build();

var authRequestUrl = confidentialClientApplication.GetAuthorizationRequestUrl(scopes);
string authorizationCode = "Code";
AuthenticationResult authResult = await confidentialClientApplication.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(scopes, authorizationCode).ExecuteAsync();

Console.WriteLine("Access token: {0}", authResult.AccessToken);
```

[image]

By using the above access token when I tried to call the User endpoint, I got the **error** like below:

```json
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/UserID/profile/certifications
```

[image]

Hence, **to resolve the error** instead of calling **`/users`** endpoint call **`/me`** endpoint to fetch the certificates of signed-in user:

```json
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/profile/certifications
```

[image]

According to the MsDoc, **`User.Read.All`** API permission does not support Microsoft Account and hence you are facing 401 error while access **`/users`**  endpoint. These permissions are only available for work or school accounts (Azure AD accounts).

- To access the `certifications` for a personal Microsoft account, you can use the **`User.Read`** permission and call the **`/me`** endpoint instead of the `/users/id` endpoint.

**UPDATE:**

To fetch the data from MS learn profile is not possible is no sync between your certifications in Microsoft Learn and /me/profile/certifications. Please raise a feature request.

**Reference:**

[Overview of Microsoft Graph permissions - Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-overview?tabs=http#delegated-permissions)

Comment: Thank you @Rukmini for the detailed explanation. A couple of quick questions. 1. In case of personal MS account is it mandatory to use AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode() method? If yes then how I can generate the Autherization Code? 2. I'm generating the token using AcquireTokenForClient() method. and passing the scope as string[] scopes = new string[] { $"{clientId}/.default" }; This brings me to a new error 'Access token validation failure. Invalid audience.' Appreciate your help.

Comment: You have to pass scope as `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default` not clientid/. default

Comment: Thank you @Rukmini. Now I'm getting Error: "/me request is only valid with delegated authentication flow." I'm using below statement to generate token: confidentialClientApplication.AcquireTokenForClient(scopes).ExecuteAsync();

Comment: Yes as you are using client credential flow you cannot use /me

Comment: Make use of `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/userid/profile/certifications` endpoint

Comment: Thank you so much @Rukmini. Looks like there is something wrong with my account itself. Even after using Microsoft graph explorer, I'm not able to fetch the list of certificates. I have submitted another question for the same. Once that will be fixed then I'll try from code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76935438/fetch-microsoft-certifications-list-from-ms-learn-profile-using-graph-apis

Comment: As you are using personal account it only supports user.read permission with /me endpoint. And for this to work you have to make use of Authorisation code flow

Comment: are you sure that you are able to fetch your certifications from Microsoft Learn profile using the example you shared above? I recently received a comment on my another question that there is no sync between your certifications in Microsoft Learn and /me/profile/certifications.

Comment: I created the certificates using post and then fetched it

Comment: Ahh, got it, sorry but my question was about fetching Certifications from Microsoft Learn Profile.

Comment: Thank you @Rukmini, for your time and efforts. Your answer is absolutely perfect to fetch data from certification object of MS user, But my question was on to fetch the data from MS learn profile, which is not possible at the moment.

Comment: I updated the answer with the details.