# Fetch Microsoft certifications list from MS learn profile using Graph APIs

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, graph-explorer

I have a Microsoft learn profile connected to my personal Microsoft account.

[image]

I am trying to fetch the list of certifications using graph API from graph explorer. I have logged into to graph explorer using the same Microsoft Account.

[image]

I'm getting no result with `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/profile/certifications` URL. Is there anything I'm missing here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no sync between your certifications in Microsoft Learn and `/me/profile/certifications`.

At least nothing mentioned in the documentation whether the sync is supported and from which data source.

You need to [add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profile-post-certifications?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) all certifications manually for now.

But I would suggest to create a feedback whether the sync is intended in the future. Click on the button **This page** at the bottom of the [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/personcertification?view=graph-rest-beta).

Comment: Thank you for clarification. I don't see any point in adding manual certifications. Not sure if this is the right use case of /profile/certifications.